# Ubuntu not shutting down properly

Tags: shutdown, error-handling

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP Pavilion g6 Notebook. It is working all fine except when I try to shut it down, it gets unresponsive. It would display some processes and hangs up. I am new to this OS so I don't know up the problem could be. I don't know what is happening.

Also, sometimes it shows an error message saying:

> Sorry, Some Internal Error has occured.

And then it asks for checking online for solution, but that has also not provide any help.

Comment: Can you take screenshot/photo with camera of your situation?

Answer (score 2):

Try to shut down from terminal.

1. While you are at your desktop GUI, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (not yet).
2. Log in with your credentials.
3. Type: `sudo shutdown now`

   There you may have a better screen to see what’s happening, when the shutdown process begins, normally may be a "service/daemon" or driver taking more time to be killed

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of that fixed my issue (related to graphics card update) when I had a similar problem was to update grub.

`sudo update-grub`

Once you've done that try shutting down and restarting a few times. If it works and in future it happens again run the above command.